# Magento 2 Pagination, from page 2 no results found

Tags: magento2, pagination

I have an issue on my production site running magento 2.3.3, results of pagination from the page 2 and above don't show any results to be more clear:

- https://mywebsite/products?p=1 -> function correctly.
- https://mywebsite/products?p=2 -> no products could be found.
- ...
- https://mywebsite/products?p=4 -> no products could be found.

The problem is not only on the product category page but for everywhere pagination is used (for search as well).

I can't reproduce the issue locally any idea how I can debug or solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is know bug and Magento team / community member has already worked on it, please look at the pull request - https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25379

you can create the patch and apply the fix following the instructions from this article - https://www.classyllama.com/blog/create-apply-patches-magento-2

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: issue was solved by applying the patch thanks!

Comment: can you please share patch link